# call to a function that changes picture every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a picture and i want to change it every 2 seconds when my mouse is on it.
so i write:

```
$("#profilePic").mouseover(function() {
    var t = setTimeout("pictureChanger()",2000);
});
```

and this is the function:

```
function pictureChanger() {
    currentPicture++;
    currentPicture = currentPicture % NUM_PICTURES;
    $("#profilePic").src = pictures[currentPicture];
}
```

it doesn't work.. however when i write `$("#profilePic").src = pictures[currentPicture];` inside the function of `mouseover` it does replace the picture. so i guess the problem is with the function `pictureChanger`..
how to i fix it so that the function will replace my pictures?

thank you!

Comment: Where is `currentPicture` initially defined? Also, you probably want `setInterval()` to change the picture every 2 seconds, rather than a single `setTimeout`

Comment: right. changed that to `setInterval()`. `currentPicture` is defined globally so everytime i will run `pictureChanger()` i will remember which picture i showed previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to set attributes in jquery:

```
$('#profilePic').attr('src', pictures[currentPicture]);
```

Or get the underlying DOM element from the array of matched elements by the selector:

```
$('#profilePic').get(0).src = pictures[currentPicture];
```

The first is prefered because if the selector doesn't match any DOM elements the code will break whereas with the first example it will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `()` and the quotes of the function name in the setTimeout:

```
var t = setTimeout(pictureChanger,2000);
```